# getline() carries '\n' from csv

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to get data from a .csv file using getline, but it doesn't stop at the new line character. Code:

```
while (file.good()) {
        getline(file, value, ',');
}
```

My .csv is in the following format:

```
123 456
789 000
```

When getting data from the second column, getline returns `456\n789`. How to fix it?

Comment: You told it to use commas instead.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `good()` to check for end of input. Change the loop to `while(getline(file, value, ',')) { ... }`. That way the loop body won't execute when the read fails at the end of the file.

Comment: The easy solution is to parse twice. Use `while (getline(file, line))` to get lines. Inside the `while` body, write the line into a stringstream, and use `while (getline(stream, value, ','))`  to get the resulting values on the  line.

Comment: @user4581301: Answer section is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::getline()` without any delimiters, to read one line at a time from your file.

Then, take the `std::string`, construct a `std::istringstream`, then use `std::getline()`, with the ',' delimiter, to read the individual comma-separated fields.